# Recovering messages from rabbitmq queue in mule

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, mule, mule-studio

I am very much new to Mule ESB.

I have created a flow which has multiple queues(I am using `RabbitMQ`). The flow is something like some messages are put into first queue which will be read by second queue which will be read be third and so on.

**Note:** I am sending messages concurrently using `JMeter`.

Let's say before all message(s) can be put into third queue from second queue, my rabbitmq server is stopped. Now, in this case, I want to recover my messages. Also, I should be able to know what messages have been put into third queue and what are still left.

I might not have put my question in elegant or understandable way but i hope you understood what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rollback Exception strategy (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Rollback+Exception+Strategy) along with transactions: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management when properly implemented messages that have not been delivered to the second queue will be rolled back automatically.

In rollback exception strategy you can write your custom behavior. Why don't you use rabbitmq client to see what messages where in third queue?